# 500 Internal Server Error after moving wordpress from localhost to web server

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I developed a wordpress website on localhost (xampp). But when i uploaded it to webserver, 500 internal server error occurs.
I did some changes after uploading it to server:

- changed database settings
- changed the wp-options table (**site_url** and **home**)
- changed root .htaccess file

.htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried to rename the plugins but error is not gone.

Comment: Check Apache error.log for the reason of 500 error

Answer (score 0):

Check if your LIVE server supports the PHP version you require. The standard minimum **right now** is PHP 5.4 **(DISCARDED)**

Hope this helps: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/

It's a list for common 500 internal server error in Wordpress

Check the **error.log** file. You will get more information there.

Comment: Server version of php is 5.5.26